# Number of connected sets of size $k$ containing a given vertex on $\mathbb{Z}^d$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistical-mechanics

Consider the graph $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Let $C_k$ be the number of connected sets containing the origin and $k-1$ other vertices. How does
$C_k$ grow with $k$?

Comment: In dimension $d=2$, if $A_k$ is the number of [fixed polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Free.2C_one-sided.2C_and_fixed_polyominoes), then you have $C_k=k\cdot A_k$.  According to Wikipedia, the sequence of the $A_k$ [has exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Asymptotic_growth_of_the_number_of_polyominoes). Incidentally, the sequence of the $C_k$ is [A048664 of the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A048664).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking (up to some scaling factor) for the number of $d$-dimensional polycubes of size $n$. [Barequet, Barequet, and Rote](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/users/Rote/Papers/pdf-gzipped/Formulae+and+growth+rates+of+high-dimensional+polycubes.pdf.gz) have written about this.  It's known that it grows like $\lambda_d^n$ for some constant $\lambda_d$.  In the $d = 2$ case it's known that $\lambda_2 \in [4.0025, 4.5276]$ (this is called "Klarner's constant"); numerically it appears to be around 4.062570 (see e. g. [this presentation of Knuth](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/flaj2014.pdf)). Barequet, Barequet, and Rote show that $\lambda_d = 2ed - o(d)$ as $d \to \infty$.  But nobody seems to have written down any numerical estimates for $\lambda_3$, at least nobody I could find quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is also this related question ;-)

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608352/number-of-connected-subsets-of-a-finite-connected-set-in-mathbbzd